# does a==b and b==a give same results in python

Tags: python

I am learning python and wrote this code.

```
name = input("Enter your name \n")
name = name.lower()
for i in range(0, len(name)):
if name[i] == "":  # investigate
    pass
elif name.count(name[i]) > 1:
    print(f"The number of times {name[i]} appears in {name} is {name.count(name[i])}")
    name = name.replace(name[i], "")
else:
    print(f"The number of times {name[i]} appears in {name} is {name.count(name[i])}")
```

getting an error sometimes and pycharm is asking to flip name[i] == "": to "" == name[1]

Comment: Note that you said name[i] and name[1] which are very different.

Comment: Yes. a==b and b==a are same.

Comment: In *general* this isn't the case, but here it is.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) on Value comparisons say :

> Numbers of **built-in numeric types** (Numeric Types — int, float, complex) and of the standard library types fractions.Fraction and decimal.Decimal can be compared within and across their types, with the restriction that complex numbers do not support order comparison. Within the limits of the types involved, **they compare mathematically (algorithmically) correct** without loss of precision.

Emphasis mine. So as long as you're using the built-in numerics without going over their range/accuracy, a==b is always equal to b==a. However,

> **User-defined classes** that customize their comparison behavior should follow some consistency rules, if possible:
>
> Comparison **should be symmetric**. In other words, the following expressions should have the same result:
>
> x == y and y == x
>
> **Python does not enforce** these consistency rules. In fact, the not-a-number values are an example for not following these rules.

This means when you're using other types, there's a possibility `a==b` return different result from `b==a`. The compiler won't enforce that.

As for the IDE suggesting to flip `name[i] == ""` to `"" == name[i]`, this is just to prevent accidental assignment when you meant to compare, since `name[i]=""` is a valid statement (though it's not valid where a boolean value is expected) while `""=name[i]` is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you get this error because of your index can be out of range. Because in your for loop you are replacing the letter if its greater than 0.

For example: if you use "letter" name then

on the first iteration : `The number of times l appears in letter is 1` (name=letter)

on the second: `The number of times e appears in letter is 2`(name=lttr)

on the third: `The number of times t appears in letter is 2` (name=lr)

as you see on each iteration your name is changed and at the end it will give you an index error. I hope i could explain it.

Comment: and maybe that's why only "sometimes" you got this error. It depends on the input that you entered :)